# Where i put my module/class in ROR MVC architecture

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have made a module named

```
module ConstantModelName
 AIRPORT =  "Airport"
end
```

It contains all the constant values used in my application.
So where should i place this module in my application.

currently i placed it in **lib** folder in my app.

Give your valuable comments.

Thanks

Comment: Just interesting what's the reason to create such module? I mean that usually constant is created in related module..

Answer (score 3):

lib folder is the correct place for it